# Javascript - Remove duplicate arrays from a set

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, set

I have an array of arrays.

```
let myArr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[5,6,7]];
```

I want to filter all repeating arrays in `myArr` so it stores only unique ones:

```
let myArr = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]];
```

I thought that by converting `myArr` into a set it would clear all 'duplicate' values, however, it did not:

```
let mySet = new Set(myArr);
// Set is: {[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[5,6,7]}
```

How can I properly filter `myArr` to hold only unique elements?

Comment: equality for arrays is not well defined, for example, are these "equal": `[1,2,3] vs [1,,2,,3]`?  Or `[1,"2"] vs ["1",2]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take stringed arrays as value for the set and map then the arrays back.

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]],
    unique = Array.from(
        new Set(array.map(a => JSON.stringify(a))),
        json => JSON.parse(json)
    );
    
console.log(unique);
```

If you need the original arrays, then you could filter with a `Set`.

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]],
    unique = array.filter(
        (s => a => (j => !s.has(j) || s.set(j))(JSON.stringify(a)))
        (new Set)
    );
    
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON to identify duplicates in a set and keep only the unique arrays in your list.

```
const elem_sets = new Set();
const result = arr.filter(item => !elem_sets.has(JSON.stringify(item)) ? elem_sets.add(JSON.stringify(item)) : false);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function remove(myArr) {
    let s = new Set(myArr);
    let it = s.values();
    return Array.from(it);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with a single `Array.reduce` where you group on the `Array.toString()`:

```js
const data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]

const r = Object.values(data.reduce((r,c) => (r[c.toString()] = c, r), {}))

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqWith) you can filter the Array:

```
const myArr = _.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual);
```

And than  convert to a Set with Vanilla JS:

```
const mySet = new Set(uniqueArr)
```